# Solving for a matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

Assume that M is a n by n matrix, show that there exists M such that $M^5-M-I=0$.

I have been trying to use caley-hamilton thm (and maybe use the characteristic polynomial to find an upper triangular matrix) but since I cannot factor x^5-x-1=0, I do not think I can apply the theorem here. I am a bit stuck on what approach to take here.

Comment: Read up on Companion matrices

Comment: does the companion matrix satisfy this relation? or any relation M^some power-M-I=0?

Comment: The companion matrix for the polynomial $x^5-x-1$, satisfies $M^5-M-I=0$. How to construct the matrix, is given on Wikipedia.

Comment: The statement in question is not true in general. E.g. when $n=1$ and the field is $GF(2)$, $M^5-M-I=0$ is insolvable. On the other hand, if $n=5$, the companion matrix for the polynomial $x^5-x-1$ is always annihilated by that polynomial, regardless of the underlying field. If the field is real, you don't even need companion matrix. Just pick a real root $\lambda$ of $x^5-x-1=0$ and set $M=\lambda I_n$. This works for all $n\ge1$.

Comment: thank you, what about the case of $M^3-M-I=0$? is that also insolvable in a few cases?

Comment: That doesn't change anything. $M^3-M-I=0$ is still insolvable when $n=1$ over $GF(2)$.

Comment: oh got it, so it has to be a real field, thank you

Comment: would it be possible for you to elaborate the last part on if the field is real and i can just pick a real root (in an answer format or just comment)? I am a bit confused sorry

Answer (score 0):

The statement in question is not true in general. E.g. it is not solvable when $n=1$ and the underlying field is $GF(2)$. On the other hand, if $n=5$, the equation is satisfied by setting $M$ as the companion matrix for the polynomial $x^5-x-1$, regardless of the underlying field.

If the quintic equation $x^5-x-1=0$ is solvable over the underlying field (it is always solvable if the field is algebraically closed; it is also solvable when the field is $\mathbb R$, because the polynomial has an odd degree), then you don't need companion matrices. You can simply pick a root $\lambda$ of the equation and set $M=\lambda I_n$.

Comment: what is the underlying reason/theory that i can just pick a root out of the equation and set M equal to root times identity matrix?

Comment: like i verfied your answer by solving $()^5--$ by hand which is obviously 0 since we end up with $^5--1$  on every diagonal; but i am wondering how you came up with knowing to pick M=?